I want to create a Django Apllication for a french compnay but using 'iso-8859-1' encoding not UTF-8 how i can do that?
I have added these 2 lines in settings file of the Django App:
FILE_CHARSET = 'iso-8859-1'
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'iso-8859-1'

And in html page that I want to render it. I specified , the encoding but I always got error UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 9348: ordinal not in range(256) because of the name 'système'  in the line English: système load is very high of my html template.
How can I resolve it?

Keep UTF-8 Everywhere, see also UTF-8 all the way through as well as
Django charset and encoding

In fact I am obliged in ISO-88591 Because i am migrating a live project to Django and all live customers have databases in Latin1 as also their html pages

But is the content actually iso-8859-1? Python internally, would be using Unicode, so Django would be using Unicode and then transcoding to ISO-8859-1. I suspect from the error the data you are trying to use is Windows-1252, which does have an 8-bit charcater equivalent to U+2019. But iso-8859-1 doesn't. The HTML encoding specification uses the Windows-1252 encoder/decoder for ISO-8859-1. Anything on the web labelled as iso-8859-1 uses windows-1252 to transcode. Whereas Python is strict. if its Windows-1252 but being parse as ISO-8859-1 you can get encoding errors for characters in C1.

Try setting your encoding to Windows-1252 instead of ISO-8859-1, and see if error persists.

I tried use Windows-1252 it doesn't work, the idea that the old project that i am migrate to Django use  iso-8859-1 in hmtl content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" and the database encoding is latin1 and the old framework is CGI and its working fine and the project is french there is letters like é à etc.. they should be visible i can n ot mask them so what do you think?

"so what do you think? –"  - just go for utf-8.
You are not mixing pages, right? pages served from django will not be visible as part of a legacy page  >If you are not migrating the legacy databases, just use the legacy encoding in the DB connection - when data gets into Python, it should already be encoding agnostic text, and jsut work utf-8 - django's default from there on.

seriously: you obviously do not understand a whole lot about encoding - at least yet. Trying to "migrate things half way" may land the entire project in an unmaintanable and fragile situation. Your best choice would be hiring a consultant to explain you the enconding intricacies and set those options for you.
